# Latest date and time in SQL without ORDER BY

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find a way to display the last event held (last date and time) in an events table whilst displaying all the columns for that event without using ORDER BY.

For example:

```
SELECT * from Events
where dateheld in (select max(dateheld) from events)
AND starttime in (select max(starttime) from events)
```

When I put MAX starttime, it displays nothing. When I put MIN starttime it works but displays the earliest time of that date and not the latest.

Comment: People, please quit voting to close. This is a real question from someone that is trying to learn. Right now OP is learning why you don't store date and time in separate fields, but sometimes that is out of the developers hands, and it's useful to know how to deal with those situations.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could print out your records, throw them down the stairs, and the ones that go farthest have the "lightest" dates. You cannot sort without order by. It's like wanting water that isn't wet. Unless your data naturally comes out in the order you want, you MUST sort.

Of course, if you want only the record that has the absolute most recent date, and don't need more than just that one record, then

```
SELECT yourdatetimefield, ...
FROM yourtable
HAVING yourdatetimefield = MAX(yourdatetimefield)
```

Comment: Yeh I'm not trying to sort the data. I'm trying to find the last date and time to verify that event was the last one. For example SELECT * from Events
where dateheld in (select max(dateheld) from events)
AND starttime in (select max(starttime) from events) - It doesn't work so I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: do you get anything when you run the two subqueries individually/manually?

Comment: Yes, I get either the latest time within the table or the latest date and all the times within that last date

Comment: However, you're doing two different comparisons on two different fields. The max record may be `Sep 12/2012 6pm`, but if you've got `Jan 1/2012 11:59pm`, then max(time) is going to be 11:59, and max(date) is going to be Sep 12 - parts of two completely separate records. There's almost no need to store separate date AND time values like this - mysql's datetime field can handle both tog3ether, and then you don't run into this kind of split record problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for the latest item:

**EDIT** gets a little more complicated when you have seperate date and time fields, but this should work. This is a ridiculous kludge for a situation where date and time should be stored in one field.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Events
  WHERE dateTime = (SELECT MAX(dateheld) FROM Events)
) temp
WHERE starttime = (SELECT MAX(starttime) FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM Events
  WHERE dateTime = (SELECT MAX(dateheld) FROM Events)
) temp 2 )
```

Comment: Yeh that's what I've tried but I have the MAX dateheld MAX timeheld to account for

Comment: @slc4eva -  OK, check out my edit and see if that works for you.